# JSP -- Make An Object Visible Across Pages

Tags: jsp

I have an object that is defined and initiated in one page as in

```
<...>
<...>
<%
   Thing o = new Thing();
   // on and on
%>
<...>
```

But, I have another page that needs to access `o`'s fields as in

```
<...>
<...>
<! o.name>
<...>
```

I need to be able to use the same object across pages. I have heard a lot about session scope, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jspsessions.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well did you try to put it and get it from session object?

```
session.setAttribute("key", value);
session.getAttribute("key");
```